# Can I implement chatting feature using firebase without firebase auth in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I am working on a project where I have implement authentication using API from php/laravel backend.Now I have to implement chatting feature in my app using firebase.I have seen many tutorials where everyone using google sign up option by firebase authentication but I have already implement auth and getting a user id. Is there any way to implement chatting using firebase without firebase auth?
 `"id": 2, "first_name": "MD Mustafizur",`

Comment: Yes you can use firebase firestore database without authentification.

Comment: thanks for the answer. By any chance do you have any solution to implement chat without firebase auth or any tutorial will so helpful.

Comment: Will do help you.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to craft an app that allows users to exchange data (a chat)? Is there something preventing you from writing that code as it's fairly basic if you have experience with Firebase and doesn't require any authentication what-so-ever. Reading and Writing data is covered in the Getting Started guide along with how to use listeners to notify your app of changes (like an incoming chat msg)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to require your users to sign in, consider using Firebase's [**anonymous** authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/anonymous-auth#authenticate_with_firebase_anonymously) provider. This gives users a unique UID without requiring them to enter any credentials, with this code:

```
try {
  final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  print("Signed in with temporary account.");
  print("UID: ${userCredential.user.uid}");
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  switch (e.code) {
    case "operation-not-allowed":
      print("Anonymous auth hasn't been enabled for this project.");
      break;
    default:
      print("Error: $e");
  }
}
```